# SetSortOrder does not work in People API Google Java Spring Boot

Tags: java

I'm new to using the Google People API. I've been reading the official documentation and recently I've been having issues with the way the API returns my contacts. The default order set according to the documentation is LAST_MODIFIED_ASCENDING, but I want it to be sorted alphabetically, FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING. I've set the value in the API call but it still doesn't work and continues with the default value. I have no idea why or if I'm doing something wrong somewhere. If anyone can enlighten my ignorance, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is the code I have made:

```
public List<ContactDTO> getAllContacts2() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    PeopleService service = authorizedAPI();
    List<ContactDTO> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    ListConnectionsResponse fullSyncResponse = service.people().connections().list("people/me")
            .setSortOrder("FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING")
            .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,biographies")
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setRequestSyncToken(true)
            .execute();
    
    contacts = fullSyncResponse.getConnections().stream().map(this::mapToContactDTO).toList();
    
    return contacts;
}

private ContactDTO mapToContactDTO(Person person) {

    String firstname = person.getNames() != null && !person.getNames().isEmpty()
            ? person.getNames().get(0).getGivenName()
            : "None";

    String lastname = person.getNames() != null && !person.getNames().isEmpty()
            ? person.getNames().get(0).getFamilyName()
            : "None";

    String phone = person.getPhoneNumbers() != null && !person.getPhoneNumbers().isEmpty()
            ? person.getPhoneNumbers().get(0).getValue()
            : "None";

    String email = person.getEmailAddresses() != null && !person.getEmailAddresses().isEmpty()
            ? person.getEmailAddresses().get(0).getValue()
            : "None";

    String notes = person.getBiographies() != null && !person.getBiographies().isEmpty()
            ? person.getBiographies().get(0).getValue()
            : "None";

    return ContactDTO.builder()
            .firstname(firstname)
            .lastname(lastname)
            .phone(phone)
            .email(email)
            .notes(notes)
            .build();
}
```